# taglist incorrectly parse Javascript in vim

Tags: vim, javascript

I'm using `taglist.vim` to display functions in vim. It works fine for C++ and C source files, but not very well for Javascript files.

What should I do to make the Javascript files parsed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833531/vim-javascript-doctorjs-jsctags-and-taglist-source-code-browsing) over on [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vim%20javascript%20taglist%20tagbar)